# instagram api - oAuth - users get the sandbox

Tags: api, oauth, instagram

I have a question, about the Instagram Api oAuth. create a small api, which users allow to generate a instagram api token key. but, my problem is, when I log in with my account, the source works. But, when someone other with a different account want to lo in. the get this back:

```
{"error_message": "You are not a sandbox user of this client", "error_type": "OAuthForbiddenException", "code": 403}
```

I don't know, what the hell the problem is? maybe in the Valid redirect URIs? I have there the same URL like website url? Do I have to submit in the end of the url? something? I have read down the docu: instagram.com/ oAuth. I followed these steps:

**first:**

sign up to my developer account:

then register a new client:

website URL: mywebsitecom/token/

Valid redirect URIs: mywebsitecom/token/

the app should work so: user click on the button >> then it will be forward to the oauth >> after authorize the app >> the user will get the token key on the same page or site  `website/token/#access_token=1920579593.4ca8793.a66f6aa9d40243afa282735f707b58b3`

how can i doing that? i dont know, where the problme is.. 
the app is with   Disable implicit OAuth:

Here is my source:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

        <title>Instagram API Access Token KEY Generator – by Lucas Gatsas</title>

        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png">

        <meta name="description" content="Quickly generate an access token for Instagram to display your photos on your website.">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="assets/js/javascript.modify.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/stylesheet.css">

        <script type="text/javascript">

          (function(){$(function(){var n,t,o,c;return c=function(){return o()?($(document.body).addClass("token-received"),t()):$(document.body).addClass("no-token"),n()},o=function(){var n;return n=window.location.hash,!!(n.length&&n.indexOf("access_token")>-1)},t=function(){var n;return n=window.location.hash.split("#access_token=")[1],$(".instagram-access-token").val(n).on("click",function(){return $(this).select()})},n=function(){return Modernizr.svg?void 0:$(".logo").attr("src",$(".logo").data("backup-png"))},c()})}).call(this);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="site-header-wrapper">
            <header class="site-header" role="banner">
                <img src="assets/img/Instagram-logo.png" style=" width 200px;
                     display contents;
                     margin 0 auto;
                     text-align center;
                     display -webkit-box;">

            </header>
        </div>
        <div class="site-content-wrapper">
            <div class="site-content" role="main">
                <div class="pre-token">
                    <div class="token-button-wrapper">
                        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=6ca879341cd14455bd12f4fb93515ed9&redirect_uri=http://lucasgatsas.ch/token/&response_type=token" class="button" title="Generate Instagram Access Token">Generate Token Key</a>
                    </div>

                    <p>You'll be brought right back here and, if all went well, your Instagram Access Token will be ready for you. Copy and paste this access token into the correct field. Remember to keep your access token private and never paste it in a location where others might can access it.</p>
                    <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://lucasgatsas.ch/token" data-text="Check Out the Instagram Access Token Api Key Generator" data-size="large" data-hashtags="instagram">Tweet</a>
                    <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
                    <code>
                        https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=token
                    </code>
                    <h1>Docu:</h1>
                    <p><a href="https://www.instagram.com/developer/" target="_blank">Instagram Developers</a></p>
                    <p><a href="https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/" target="_blank">oAuth2 - Authentication</a></p>
                    <p><a href="https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/" target="_blank">oAuth2 - Authentication</a></p>

                    <h1>Links:</h1>
                    <p><a href="https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-12" target="_blank">oAuth V.2</a></p>
                    <div class="post-token">
                        <h2>It worked!</h2>
                        <p>Use this token in the appropriate field on your website or blog, and you should have a working Instagram widget.</p>
                        <div class="token-input-wrapper">
                            <input class="instagram-access-token" type="text" value="" size="50">
                        </div>
                        <p>Are you have any Question to the Api Token Key. Please feel free to contact me <a href="mailto:space@lucasgatsas.ch">Contact Me.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="site-footer-wrapper">
                <footer class="site-footer">
                    <p>©.2017 by  <a href="http://lucasgatsas.ch">Lucas Gatsas</a></p>
                </footer>
            </div>

            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script>window.jQuery || document.write("<script src='scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js'><\/script>")</script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                (function () { $(function () { var n, t, o, c; return c = function () { return o() ? ($(document.body).addClass("token-received"), t()) : $(document.body).addClass("no-token"), n() }, o = function () { var n; return n = window.location.hash, !!(n.length && n.indexOf("access_token") > -1) }, t = function () { var n; return n = window.location.hash.split("#access_token=")[1], $(".instagram-access-token").val(n).on("click", function () { return $(this).select() }) }, n = function () { return Modernizr.svg ? void 0 : $(".logo").attr("src", $(".logo").data("backup-png")) }, c() }) }).call(this);
            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope some one can give me tips?

Answer (score 0):

Your client isn't accessible by every user. You need to invite the user you are testing with as a "Sandbox User".

Navigate to "Manage Clients" and click "Manage" for the client you wish to use. Choose the tab "Sandbox" and add the user you are testing with.

As you can see your own account is added by default by Instagram.

Best of luck

Comment: Thanks  a lot, sounds great, didn't finish project till now, but i will try it out now. and come back to you if does work. peace L.